# Use .group() to rename files with regex

Tags: python, regex

I need to rename files which starts with numbers from a given directory, the files I have are like this:

```
"my_folder/1. file_one.csv"
"my_folder/2.file_two_1.csv"
"my_folder/file_three.csv"
"my_folder/file_four.csv"
```

I want the files with as this:

```
"my_folder/file_one.csv"
"my_folder/file_two_1.csv"
"my_folder/file_three.csv"
"my_folder/file_four.csv"
```

So I need to remove when it exists:

1. The digit at the begging
2. The dot
3. The space

My first try was to use following regex:

```
re.sub('\d.\s*','',name)
```

but it brakes the name of the file is cases like:

"2.file_two_1.csv" --> "file_two_csv"

I got an error when I try to use .group()

```
re.sub('/(\d.\s*)','',name).group(1)
"'unicode' object has no attribute 'group' "
```

Is it possible to use .group() for cases like that one?

PD. I know I can solve the issue using this expression instead:

```
re.sub('/(\d.\s*)','/',name)
```

My question is regarding the use of the .group method or any similar approach.

Comment: `re.sub` returns a string, so you can't use `group` on that string. If you want you can use `re.match` instead

Comment: Maybe you just need `re.sub(r'/\d+\.\s*([^/]*)$', r'/\1', s)`. When *matching*, to access groups, check if there is a match first.

Answer (score 2):

One approach using `os` would be:

```
a = 'my_folder/1. file_one.csv'    
os.path.join(os.path.split(a)[0], re.sub('^\d\.\s*','',os.path.split(a)[1]))
```

Outputs: `'my_folder/file_one.csv'`

`^` will make sure the regular expression only happens at the start of the string.

Also notice the `\.` as you want to delete when a single dot is met. In regular expressions a single dot means any character.